# Keras layer input as a function of weights and bias

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I'm confused about how bias terms are implemented in Keras neural networks.  To be more specific, consider the following example:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
encoded = Dense(1000, activation='relu')(input_img)  # L1
encoded = Dense(2, activation='relu')(encoded)       # L2
decoded = Dense(20, activation='relu')(encoded)      # L3
decoded = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(decoded)   # L4
mymodel = Model(input_img, decoded)
```

mymodel.layers[2].get_weights()[1] returns an array of 2 elements, which let's denote by B.  mymodel.layers[3].get_weights()[0] returns an 20x2 array, which let's denote by W.

Suppose the output of the L2 layer is X, which should also be a vector of 2 elements.  What is the equation relating the input of L3 and (X, B, W)?  In Matlab-like notation, is it input(L3) = W*(X+B)?  (Assuming X & B are column vectors of 2 elements.)  Thanks a lot!

(Originally I was expecting L2 to have a scalar bias term (b), and input(L3)=W*[X; b], but this apparently wasn't what Keras did.)

Comment: The input of L3 is the output of L2, which is `X`. The **output** of L3 is `mymodel.layers[3].get_weights()[0] * X + mymodel.layers[3].get_weights()[1]`.

Comment: In fact, it'll be `X * W` since `X` is a batch of vectors, not a single vector. Also, `W` will be a 2x20 array, not 20x2.